# Javascript: Concat boolean functions

Tags: javascript, filter, boolean, concatenation

I want to write a method which filters data for multiple criteria. These criteria should by passed as functions to the filter-function, for example:

```
var products = [/* some data */];
function filterMyProducts(criteria) {
   return products.filter(/* I'm asking for this code */);
}

function cheap(product) {
    return product.price < 100;
}

function red(product) {
    return product.color == "red";
}

// find products that are cheap and red
var result = filterMyProducts([cheap, red]);
```

How can I combine the criteria passed in the array to the filter-function? I want them to be combined with a boolean **AND**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function validateProduct(listOfFunctions) {
    return function(currentProduct) {
        return listOfFunctions.every(function(currentFunction) {
            return currentFunction(currentProduct);
        });
    }
}

function filterMyProducts(criteria) {
    return products.filter(validateProduct(criteria));
}
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/QPLq2/)

Comment: How do I combine them with a boolean **OR**?

Comment: @user2033412 Instead of `listOfFunctions.every` you have to use `listOfFunctions.some` to get the boolean `OR` behavior :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use `reduce` function here, something like this:

```
function filterMyProducts(criteria) {
  return criteria.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.filter(curr)
  }, products)
}
```

Comment: +1 This is really awesome, but OP likes to do boolean OR as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this version be more expensive due to the many new arrays that will be created by each filter-call?

Comment: Yes it might be I think. It just is shorter and "prettier" to me. So if your arrays are not terribly big, it is quite usable. For general cases, @thefourtheye's answer is better.